# How to replace constant expression string for Arquillian test?

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, jboss-arquillian

In my enterprise application I have simple class:

```
package org.my_package;

public class Configuration {
    public static final String BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX = "";   
}
```

And for Aquilliran test I want to replace this class with class as below:

```
package org.my_package;

public class Configuration {
    public static final String BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX = "Mock";   
}
```

Notice that value of BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX has to be a constans expression.

It is used in the following way:

```
@EJB(beanName = "MyBean" + Configuration.BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX)
private MyBean myBean; // I swap those implementations
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you considered reflections?

Comment: Not, and I honestly do not see how could I use reflections in this case.

Comment: you can consider using properties, test/dev properties will define your bean_name_suffix

Comment: I can't use a properties file. Because that String has to be a constant expression. It is used in annotations.

Comment: I think that you should change the design of the app, creating an interface and implementation, so you can create an implementation for prod and implementation for test (implemented at src/test/java), and then in shrinkwrap you simply add the test class instead of the prod class.

Comment: I did have separate interface and two implementations, and thanks to code:
@EJB(beanName = "MyBean" + Configuration.BEAN_NAME_SUFFIX)
private MyBean myBean;
I swap those implementations. That's the whole point.

Comment: You can initialize constants from a properties file as long as you do it in the constructor or a static initializer.

Comment: No, I cannot. It is a compile-time constant expression. It is evaluated by compilator, not in the runtime. That's why I cannot use properties file. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28 Try use properties file in String passed to annotation, it won't compile.

Comment: Are you using CDI too? If so you can have a producer class which will `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`. Having such a construct will let you swap it for the test code easily.

Comment: Using maven or some other build tool? It is anyway needed to be set before compile. But as previous comment says it might be better to resolve this issue `@Inject` stuff.

Comment: I'm not in favor of mixing EJB and CDI since I got traped in memory leak because of that. I concluded that those both systems aren't fully compatible. To be honest, I was hoping on some solution based on ShrinkWrap.